# Audi A3 S-LINE 1,4 replacement dipped headlight beam

Tags: headlight, audi, bulbs

The light has gone on my car, and I recently went to halford to buy a bulb,

I typed by reg into their website and a list of bulbs where suggested.

I selected this one and asked them to fit it:

https://www.halfords.com/motoring/bulbs-blades-batteries/car-bulbs/h7-477-car-headlight-bulb-halfords--25-percent-longer-life-single-pack

The guy at halfords told me this was the wrong bulb and I instead needed this one,

which is a major price difference,

https://www.halfords.com/motoring/bulbs-blades-batteries/car-bulbs/d3s-42302-xenon-hid-car-headlight-bulb-manufacturers-standard-halfords-single-pack

Which bulb is the correct one?

Comment: The correct one is the one that fits - what is fitted to your car? How about a picture?

Comment: Which year is the car? It looks like both types are fitted to some A3s, so it may even have been that the Xenon lamps were an optional extra when the car was made. The best option, as Mike suggests, is to see what's already fitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on whether your particular car has HID (Xenon) headlights - the reg checker on the Halfords site only operates in terms of broad strokes - pretty much just the barest info (year and top level model). It doesn't include things like options spec so it won't know whether you have the HIDs installed if they were optional on that year's model. Putting in the reg plate for my own car (also an Audi) likewise offers both H7 and the DS3 - despite the fact that I *know* mine has the HID lights fitted and therefore the DS3 is the appropriate one.

A halogen bulb such as the H7 won't fit a car with HIDs and visa versa - the Xenon bulb's are more expensive but if that's what the car has then that's what it needs. So you don't need to be concerned that they are trying to scam you and fit a more expensive bulb then you need - you simply can't fit the DS3 to a car that has halogen lights.